# How to avoid blocking waiting for a response from websocket

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, websocket, request, response

Given the following:

```
interface IHasName
{
  string GetName();
}

class Me: IHasName
{
   private WebsocketClient _ws;

   string GetName()
   {
        return _ws.GetName();
   }
}

class WebsocketClient
{

   Map<string,RootObject> _recvMessages;
   Map<string,signal> _signals;

   //Fired when the websocket receives a messsage
   private void OnMessage(OnMessageEventArgs e)
   {
        //Deserialize data to RootObject call this obj
        //Assume we got whole message
        _recvMessages[obj.token] = obj;
        _signals[obj.token].Notify();            
   }

   public string GetName()
   {
       RootObject obj = new RootObject();
       obj.token = // Some unique token;

       _signals[obj.token] = //a synchronization signal

       Send(Serialize(obj).ToString)); //Sends the websocket message
       _signals[obj.token].wait();

        return  _recvMessages[obj.token].Name;           
   }

}


class RootObject
{
    string token;
    string Name;
}
```

So, I'm exposing IObject to my UI. I obviously do not want to block the UI, but this implementation will for sure block. I could let the UI be responsible for managing it's own asynchronous behaviour (which I'm leaning towards), my concern is that using a thread to wait for a signal on receipt of a response from a websocket looks like wastefulness.

Should I introduce a callback mechanism in the WebsockerClient, but how can i do this without exposing that callback mechanism to the IObject interface. I'm trying to keep the API simple in such that those using IObject don't need to worry if the back end is a websocket backend which would benefit from an event based system or just some datastore in memory that can immediately return the data. A suggestion someone made is to just create a thread that will poll the the websocket for data and do in fact store this in a datastore, I feel though within the system there may be more than a few of instantiations of "Me" objects, and giving responsibility to the Me object to spawn a thread and poll the distinct websockets doesn't make since. Suggestions?